# Who Creates Custom ActionMailer Layouts in Rails, You or the Client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, workflow, actionmailer, erb

When projects get large, I imagine you might start having 100s of mailer templates:

- user_signup_confirmation.html.erb
- user_signup_failure.html.erb
- user_account_activation.html.erb
- user_account_cancelation.html.erb
  ...

What is your workflow for handling this?  Do you have them email you what they want and then you mold it into a method and a template?  Or have you devised some sort of builder, or know of one, you'd like to share?  Or do you just have the client edit the ERB templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a series of sample messages that I show them with boxes around the part where they want to change up the defaults to have things relevant to their company for both Text and HTML.

More or less, I have a bunch of things that I'm used to having on a list

```
[ ] site supports users
 - user_signup_*
 - user_account_activation*
 - password_recovery.*

[ ] site has newsletter
 - news_letter_signup.*
 - news_letter_confirm
```

so, generally, i've accumulated a bunch of things that people will need if they have certain functionality and i send them some templates with some notes about what things are probably fine as it, the same as something else, or whatever.

It seems to work okay.

That said, you might want to ask the folks over at [doctype](http://doctype.com/), which is the stackoverflow-type site for designers what they do, because this is a design process question and not (necessarily) a dev process question.